# Extract IP address from a string

Tags: regular-expression, perl

The Linux `host` command returns:

```
hostA.domain.com has address xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

How do I get just the IP address and put it in the `$ipaddr` variable?

```
open(FILE, "hostlist.txt") or die("Unable to open file");
@hostnames = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
foreach $hostname (@hostnames)
{
    $lookup = qx(host $hostname);
    $ipaddr = grep ip_address $lookup;  <---- need help here
    print $ipaddr;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you posted this on the Unix & Linux site, instead of StackOverflow, I'm wondering if something like this isn't what you're looking for:

```
cat hostlist.txt | xargs resolveip -s
```

This will only return one IP address though.

Some hostnames will have multiple IP addresses associated with them:

```
$ host www.google.com
www.google.com is an alias for www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.227.18
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.227.17
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.227.16
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.227.20
www.l.google.com has address 74.125.227.19
```

To get just the list of IPs, one way to do it is:

```
host <hostname> | grep "has address" | awk '{print $4}'
```

If you want to stick with Perl, using resolveip:

```
$ipaddr = qx(resolveip -s $hostname);
```

Or to get all of the IPs, without executing any shell commands:

```
use Socket;
@ipaddrs = map { inet_ntoa($_) } (gethostbyname($hostname))[4,];
```

Comment: Note the `,` which makes it special to grab all the addresses :-) Example: `@addresses = gethostbyname($name) or die "Can't resolve $name: $!\n";
@addresses = map { inet_ntoa($_) } @addresses[4 .. $#addresses];
# @addresses is a list of IP addresses ("208.201.239.48", "208.201.239.49")`

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `dig +short`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like:

```
(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}
```

If you want something more exacting, then you'll probably have:

```
([012]?\d{1,2}\.){3}[012]?\d{1,2}
```

But even this is still somewhat loose.  For example, it still allows '269.278.287.296' to falsely match.

But both match the standard 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255.

Comment: `\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b`  would fit for all the possible and valid ip address range.

Comment: I also use http://search.cpan.org/~neely/Data-Validate-IP-0.14/lib/Data/Validate/IP.pm perl module to check if the IP address is IPV4 valid style.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @mkopala 's answer, if you have multiple hosts and you want to keep a track of them, 
build a hash, so that there is a easy reference of host to ip mapping.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Socket;
@hostnames = ('www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.facebook.com');
%ipaddrs = ();
foreach $hostname (@hostnames) {
        map { $ipaddrs{$hostname} = inet_ntoa($_) } (gethostbyname($hostname))[4,];
}
```